# Diagonal line through dynamic div

Tags: html, css

Is there an easy way to draw a diagonal line through a div? The line should go from the top left to bottom right.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a gradient

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left,#0000 49%,red ,#0000 51%);
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: couldn't find the duplicate, I know there is one (try again later)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a [`linear gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_images/Using_CSS_gradients).

Using a CSS custom property ("CSS variable") you can easily control the line width:

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.strike-through {
  --line-width: 2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent calc(50% - var(--line-width)), #f00 calc(50% - var(--line-width)), #f00 calc(50% + var(--line-width)), transparent calc(50% + var(--line-width)));
}
```

```html
<div class="container strike-through" style="height: 200px; width: 300px;"></div>
<div class="container strike-through" style="--line-width: 1px; height: 100px; width: 400px;"></div>
<div class="container strike-through" style="--line-width: 5px; height: 200px; width: 200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
  .container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
  }
  .container::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 49%, red 49%, red 51%, transparent 51%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can also use the rotate function (need to calculate the length of diagonal (.line here) with Pythagore)

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.line{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: black;
    height: 2px;
    width: 707px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What if you cannot control the `div`s aspect ratio? OP asked for a solution for *dynamic* divs, indicating they have no control over the div's  dimensions.

Comment: Yes correct @connexo should have properly read the title